# Как правильно задать ширину столбцов в Swing'е?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Изучаю пример таблицы на Swing'е, и возник такой вопрос:

[image: table]

Таблица представлена как объект DefaultTableModel, однако попытка задать ширину столбцов:

```
    infoTable.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
```

к успеху не привела, а требуемый для даных методов импорт:

```
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
```

завершился сообщением 'unused import'.

Как будет правильно настроить ширину столбцов?

Благодарю.

Comment: логи кидай сюда

Comment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - EnglishPremiership.FootballTable is not abstract and does not override abstract method removeColumnModelListener(javax.swing.event.TableColumnModelListener) in javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel
 at EnglishPremiership.FootballTable.<clinit>(FootballTable.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1                                                    (при попытке заимплементить TableColumnModel)

Comment: `table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 1 ).setPreferredWidth( 150 );` должен работать.

Comment: @zRrr Что-то по прежнему молчит.

Там, похоже, загвоздка в том что это DefaultTableModel,
а метод getColumnModel() возвращает TableColumnModel,
'недефолтный' столбец.

Вообще-то это просто демка работы Swing'а, 
просто, похоже, немного сыровата..

goo.gl/Apc8F5

Comment: @zRrr С mvc-моделью все заработало. Большое спасибо!